# Browser concatenating links instead of navigating to them

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am building a localhost website using xampp as my web server. The problem I am having is when I click on a link on my webpage it doesn't navigate to it.

Current URL:

> localhost/builds/index/

HTML Link:

```
<a href="localhost/builds/projects/30-11-11.php">30th November 2011</a>
```

Expectation:

> localhost/builds/projects/30-11-11.php

Reality:

> localhost/builds/index/**localhost/builds/projects/30-11-11.php**

**Note:**

I am aware that hard-coding anything is never a good idea. I have previously tried to use a PHP variable, but if hard-coding the link does not work I don't expect the soft-code to work at the moment either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If url doesn't start with a schema (like http:// or https://) browser will threat it a relative and append to current directory.

Answer (score 1):

The link is working correctly.  Without a leading `/`, the link is relative to the current URL.  With a leading `/`, it is relative to the domain.  Adding a `/` to the beginning of the URL in that link will make it work as you want.